# Dynamic webpage? (HTML DOM, js)

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, dom, dynamic

I'm trying to change the content in a HTML using DOM JS. Rather than getting the elements by the P tag, I want to use the DIV ID.Is this possible?

In my HTML, I have two separate DIV classes, both named the same. I want one to display depending on what button the user clicks.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" onclick="changeContent(1)" >Example 1</button>
<button type="button" onclick="changeContent(2)" >Example 2</button>

<p id="demoX"></p>

<div class="ex1">
<h1> Example 1 </h1>
<p> nothing </p>
</div>

<div id="ex1">
<h1> Example 2 </h1>
<p> more of nothing </p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function changeContent(inNum) {
    var x = document.getElementById("ex1");

    if (inNum == 1){
         document.getElementById("demoX").innerHTML = x[0].innerHTML;
    }
    else if (inNum == 2){   
     document.getElementById("demoX").innerHTML = x[1].innerHTML;
    }

}
```

How do I approach this?

Comment: `getElementById` returns a *single* element because IDs should be unique. You can change the ID for a class and use `getElementsByClassName` (note the plural for Element**s**).

Comment: Just gave this a go, and worked as a treat! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't give the same ID to more than one div so just give them both the class - 'ex1' - and then you select them by a javascript selector called `getElementsByClassName('class-name')` [replace class-name with the actual class name, in this case ex1] this function gets all the elements with this class name and stores them in an array. Then you do the logic for which button is pressed. And when a button is pressed you should set the display of the wanted div to 'block' [you should default it to hidden in CSS].

```js
function showDiv(id) {
  
  var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('ex1');
  
  if (id === 'btn1') { divs[0].style.display = 'block' }
  if (id === 'btn2') { divs[1].style.display = 'block' }
  
}
```

```css
.ex1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  display: none;
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn1' onClick='showDiv(this.id)'>button 1</button>
<button id='btn2' onClick='showDiv(this.id)'>button 2</button>

<div class='ex1'>I'm div 1</div>
<div class='ex1'>I'm div 2</div>
```

you can also change the .style thing to change the inner html as you have done in your original code.